# Smart pointers for restricted undirected graph

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

So I am a bit new to this whole smart pointer stuff. Now I am trying to use smart pointers for the following structure.

```
struct Conn {
   Node* owner; //*
   std::vector<Node*> targets; //Every node that has it as incoming gets added to here
   // Other fields
};

struct Node {};

struct NodeA : public Node {
    Conn conn{this};
    //Other fields
}

struct NodeB : public Node {
    Conn& connIn; //*
    //Other fields
}
```

'*' means initialized in Constructor

So I NodeA are sources and NodeB sinks (in reality there is also Nodes with multiple outgoing and/or incoming connectors).

I am having massive issue with memory leaks using this type of structure right now (Am using `new` currently to create the Nodes). So I thought I would take the time to properly rewrite this using smart pointers, but I just can’t figure out how to properly model this.

Anyone more experienced here willing to help?

Edit: All Nodes that are sinks, so don’t have any Conn instances themselves, are stored in a std::vector<Node *>.

Comment: I can see only blunt raw c-style pointers in your code example.

Comment: You can't. Standard smart pointers model ownership. A node in a graph does not own other nodes in the same graph. Rather, the graph owns all of its nodes. Do you have a separate class that represents a graph?

Comment: While smart pointers is a good idea to use, it's not always the right solution. I usually recommend you use smart pointers more from an *ownership* viewpoint: Can an object only have one owner, then use `std::unique_ptr`; Can an object have multiple simultaneous owners, then use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: On a side note, a reference member variable is almost always a mistake.

Comment: What is the use of the `Conn` class? Why don't your just store pointers to all adjacent nodes in your `Node` class?

Comment: The Conn class models the semantics of the output connection. There can be multiple Conn instances in a node that represent semantically different outputs of that node.

Comment: Semantically speaking a sink Node (one without Conn instances) is a (possibly shared) owner of all the Nodes that belong to the Conn references it has

Answer (score -1):

I guess one simple way to model it would be

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

/// Base class of other nodes
struct Node {
    virtual ~Node() = default;
    
    /// Use a set here to make sure we have no duplicate edges. 
    /// If you want to allow duplicate edges you can alse use a vector
    std::unordered_set<Node*> adjacents;
};

void connect(Node* a, Node* b) {
    a->adjacents.insert(b);
    b->adjacents.insert(a);
}

struct Graph {
    /// Add an arbitrary derived node to the graph
    template <typename N, typename... Args>
    requires std::derived_from<N, Node> && std::constructible_from<N, Args...> // Remove this line if you don't use C++20
    N* add(Args&&... args) {
        auto owner = std::make_unique<N>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto* node = owner.get();
        nodes.push_back(std::move(owner));
        return node;
    }
    
    /// The graph owns all the nodes. Only here do we use unique_ptrs
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes;
};

struct NodeA: Node { /* ... */ };
struct NodeB: Node { /* ... */ };

int main() {
    Graph G;
    auto* nodeA = G.add<NodeA>(/* ... */);
    auto* nodeB = G.add<NodeB>(/* ... */);
    connect(nodeA, nodeB);
    // G owns all the nodes, all get deallocated here
}
```

At least that's how I usually write a graph class if I need one.

If you want to erase nodes from your graph without destroying the whole graph, add this destructor to the `Node` class:

```
Node::~Node() {
    for (auto* N: adjacents) {
        N->adjacents.erase(this);
    }
}
```